# Google Charts Calculating and Displaying Total of Filtered Table

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a simple google chart dashboard with a control slider and table here: http://jsfiddle.net/3tzkvkzq/1/. I am looking to dynamically calculate the total of a particular column in the filtered table. The total should only include the filtered results. I am able to add an eventListener that triggers every time the table is updated by filters:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', calcTotal);

function calcTotal() {
/*This is where I would like to calculate the total of the filtered results*/
}
```

I can grab the data from the underlying, unfiltered table, but I haven't been able to find a way to get only the filtered results. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the filtered results by calling the ChartWrapper's `getDataTable` method:

```
function calcTotal() {
    var filteredData = table.getDataTable();
}
```

Comment: For those who are interested I've used this to make a table where the last row is totals of columns: http://jsfiddle.net/bpnolan08/ny6qn5o7/